# Why is the ansible vault password added to module args?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

When I run an ansible playbook

```
ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass -i vdc-inventory complete_provision.yaml -vvv
```

the password I set is sent to all `module_args`:

```
changed: [localhost] => {
    "changed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            ...
            "org": "system",
            "password": "xxx",
            ...
        }
    },
    "msg": "ABC has been created"
}
```

That is bad. It is not even redacted.

**Update 1**

When running the playbook environment variables are set with:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  environment:
    env_user: "{{ VCD_USER_NAME }}"
    env_password: "{{ VCD_USER_PASSWORD }}"
    env_host: "{{ VCD_URL }}"
```

and they are in fact module arguments...

Comment: It is sent to modules because modules may need variables in the vault file.  Still, I don't see it in the debug output.  Which module are you using?

Comment: I am using an external module [ansible-module-vcloud-director](https://github.com/vmware/ansible-module-vcloud-director)...and that password field is not showing up on regular built-in ansible modules

Comment: You might want to open an issue with VMware, I think.

Comment: Oops, I updated the question. Is there a way to hide that password in the output?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to ensure that the password doesn't show in your output, and the module is not already built to obscure it, you can use this as a module argument

```
no_log: True
```

This will suppress the output for that specific task.  Not great if you need to be able to see the output, but if the standard module doesn't support suppressing it, it might be your only option.